# JSF Catch Session Timeout

Tags: jsf, session, timeout

Is there a possibility to "intercept" the Session timeout?

I tried the `HttpSessionListener`, but as far as i can read, the Session is already destroyed, when the HttpSessionListener.sessionDestroyed()` Method is invoked. (So i have no chance to determine the user, owning the session that timed out)

Another Option would be a PhaseListener, checking if the Session is "new" in the restoreView-Phase.

However i need to perform some Actions "the second" the Session times out - not on any later refresh, and not on any future login.

(Background: Need to remove locks from certain objects, the user might have been working on when running into the timeout.)

Is there a way to achieve that?

---

Edit:
Attempt 1: Using @PreDestroy on the SessionBeans in question:

```
@SessionScoped
@Named
public class SessionBean1 implements Serializable {
   ...
  @PostConstruct
  private void pconstruct(){
     System.out.println("PostConstructing Session Bean 1");
  }
  @PreDestroy
  public void destroy(){
     System.out.println("PreDestroying Session Bean 1");
  } 
}
```

and

```
 public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        //nothing to do right here.
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        System.out.println("Session Listener says 'destroyed'.");
    }
}
```

Expected Result: destroy() beeing caled when Session times out OR user logs out.

Result: Nothing of both is happening.

```
22:29:11,199 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8090-1) ---- Started RESTORE_VIEW 1 ----
22:29:11,208 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8090-1) ---- Started RENDER_RESPONSE 6 ----
22:29:11,890 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8090-1) PostConstructing Session Bean 1
22:29:11,898 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8090-1) -- Finished Request --
22:30:11,905 INFO  [stdout] (ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[jboss.web]]) Session Listener says 'destroyed'.
```

---

Attempt 2: Trying to intercept session timeout inside the SessionListener, which is obviously taking note of the timeout:

```
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    @Inject
    private MySession mySession;

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        System.out.println("Destroying Session of owner: " + mySession.getCurrentUser().getShortName());
    }
}
```

expected result: Access to the Session bean still possible.

result: 'ContextNotActiveException':

```
22:38:57,948 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/test]] (ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[jboss.web]]) Session event listener threw exception: org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303 No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getContext(BeanManagerImpl.java:598) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:71) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:79) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at my.namespace.test$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getCurrentUser(MySession$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java) [classes:]
    at my.namespace.listener.SessionListener.sessionDestroyed(SessionListener.java:16) [classes:]
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.expire(StandardSession.java:690) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.isValid(StandardSession.java:585) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase.processExpires(ManagerBase.java:390) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase.backgroundProcess(ManagerBase.java:375) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1316) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1601) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1610) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1610) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1590) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_33]
```

---

Attempt 3: Checking the Session Attrributes for anything to use:

```
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        int i=0;
        while (se.getSession().getAttributeNames().hasMoreElements()){
            String name = se.getSession().getAttributeNames().nextElement();
            System.out.println("Checking " + name);
            Object value = se.getSession().getAttribute(name);
            System.out.println("value was: " + value);

            if (i++ == 20){
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        // nothing to do right here.
    }
}
```

expected result: List of available Attributes.

result: Infinite Loop:

```
22:47:48,025 INFO  [stdout] (ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[jboss.web]]) Checking org.jboss.weld.context.conversation.ConversationIdGenerator
22:47:48,025 INFO  [stdout] (ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[jboss.web]]) value was: org.jboss.weld.context.conversation.ConversationIdGenerator@1edd87d
22:47:48,026 INFO  [stdout] (ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[jboss.web]]) Checking org.jboss.weld.context.conversation.ConversationIdGenerator
22:47:48,027 INFO  [stdout] (ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[jboss.web]]) value was: org.jboss.weld.context.conversation.ConversationIdGenerator@1edd87d
22:47:48,028 INFO  [stdout] (ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[jboss.web]]) Checking org.jboss.weld.context.conversation.ConversationIdGenerator
22:47:48,029 INFO  [stdout] (ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[jboss.web]]) value was: org.jboss.weld.context.conversation.ConversationIdGenerator@1edd87d
```

EDIT:

Finally i used the HttpSessionListener and created - beside all the Session Scoped beans - a manual entry in the SessionMap: `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("user_id", 5)`.

This value can be accessed in the SessionListener and allows me to close all locks for the given user.

Comment: In the future questions, it'd be helpful if you show in code how exactly you tried this and that.

Comment: @BalusC Added Examples, what i tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

> *I tried the HttpSessionListener, but as far as i can read, the Session is already destroyed, when the HttpSessionListener.sessionDestroyed()` Method is invoked. (So i have no chance to determine the user, owning the session that timed out)*

I'm not sure how that forms a problem. You have still the concrete `HttpSession` instance at your hands via `HttpSessionEvent` argument on which you can just invoke `getAttribute()` method and like in order to check the logged-in user in case it's stored as a session attribute.

```
User user = (User) event.getSession().getAttribute("user");
// ...
```

---

**Update**: as per your failed attempts:

1. Not sure why `@PreDestroy` isn't invoked. That'll be a CDI implementation specific issue. It's at least not related to JSF/Servlet.
2. You should not grab an injected `@Named` instance. You should instead grab the concrete instance as session attribute directly. Use `HttpSession#getAttribute()` on the concrete managed bean name.
3. You're recreating the iterator during every iteration. You should create it once and reuse it during every iteration. Put `getAttributeNames()` outside the `while`. This issue is not related to JSF/Servlet, just basic Java.

Comment: I have a SessionScoped `mySessionBean`, that is used within the project. I used the `event.getSession.getAttributeNames().hasMoreElements()` and `event.getSession.getAttributeNames().nextElement` to check, what's in the Attribute map, when `SessionDestroy` is invoked. The iteration didn't resolve to anything, so i assumed it to be already empty (unless i didn't make a misstake)

Comment: thx for your update. 1.) *seems* to be a known issue, but it is not clear if its a bug or by design. 3.) Indeed, my bad. Iterating correct showed all available variables. Achieving 2.) is somewhat ugly, because the bean constructed by jboss has a very ugly name containing filepaths, weld proxy ids and whatevs. So im evaluating the other answer at the moment. :)

Answer (score 1):

The way I do this is to make the UserBean itself an `HttpSessionListener`. Then it still has all its own state, so it knows who it 'is', regardless of whether the session still has attributes when the callback is called or not.

Comment: I tried this, but without luck. The moment the `sessionDestroyed` method is invoked, all variables of the sessionScoped bean are already `null`. Maybe this is caused by the way JBoss is handling Session beans (Assuming, the Session bean is destroyed, before the method is invoked, ending up with a "new" (empty) session bean.).